# Dynamically changing contents of a WPF dropdown

Tags: c#, wpf

So I have these 2 dropdown boxes that should have a linked behaviour.
For example: When changing the content of the first dropdown, the content of the second should change dynamically.

```
<ComboBox x:Name="ServerCombo"
          Loaded="Servers_ComboBox_Loaded"
          DropDownClosed="Servers_ComboBox_DropDownClosed"
          SelectionChanged="ServerCombo_SelectionChanged" />
<ComboBox x:Name="BuildCombo"
          SelectionChanged="Builds_ComboBox_SelectionChanged"
          Loaded="Builds_ComboBox_Loaded"
          DropDownClosed="Builds_ComboBox_DropDownClosed" />
```

So picking a different Server will trigger the BuildCombo box to have different values.
This is the current code (a bit messy, sorry):

```
  public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }



    public void ScanBuilds(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var dialog = new System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog();
        hubBuildsList(hubPath);
    }

    public List<string> hubBuildsList(string hubPath)
    {
        string[] sDirectories = Directory.GetDirectories(hubPath);
        List<string> lDirectories = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < sDirectories.Length; i++)
        {
            string sDirectory = sDirectories[i];
            sDirectory = sDirectory.Substring(sDirectory.LastIndexOf(@"\")).Remove(0,1);
            lDirectories.Add(sDirectory);
        }
        return lDirectories;
    }

    public List<string> ServersList()
    {
        List<string> lServersList = new List<string>();
        lServersList.Add("qa02");
        lServersList.Add("qa03");
        lServersList.Add("qa04");
        return lServersList;
    }

    public void MoveBuild(string sSelectedBuild)
    {
        string a = sSelectedBuild;
        string sBuildToMove = hubPath + "\\" +  sSelectedBuild;
        string sDestinationPath = hubInstallationPath + "\\" + sSelectedBuild;
        Directory.CreateDirectory(sDestinationPath);
        DirectoryCopy(sBuildToMove, sDestinationPath);

    }

    private static void DirectoryCopy(string sourceDirName, string destDirName, bool copySubDirs = true)
    {
        // Get the subdirectories for the specified directory.
        DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(sourceDirName);

        if (!dir.Exists)
        {
            throw new DirectoryNotFoundException(
                "Source directory does not exist or could not be found: "
                + sourceDirName);
        }

        DirectoryInfo[] dirs = dir.GetDirectories();
        // If the destination directory doesn't exist, create it.
        if (!Directory.Exists(destDirName))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(destDirName);
        }

        // Get the files in the directory and copy them to the new location.
        FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles();
        foreach (FileInfo file in files)
        {
            string temppath = System.IO.Path.Combine(destDirName, file.Name);
            file.CopyTo(temppath, false);
        }

        // If copying subdirectories, copy them and their contents to new location.
        if (copySubDirs)
        {
            foreach (DirectoryInfo subdir in dirs)
            {
                string temppath = System.IO.Path.Combine(destDirName, subdir.Name);
                DirectoryCopy(subdir.FullName, temppath, copySubDirs);
            }
        }
    }

    private void hub_ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void hubCombo_DropDownClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        sSelectedhub = (string)(hubCombo.SelectedItem);
    }

    private void hub_ComboBox_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        List<string> data = hubBuildsList(hubPath);
        var comboBox = sender as ComboBox;
        comboBox.ItemsSource = data;
        comboBox.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }


    private void Servers_ComboBox_DropDownClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void Install_Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MoveBuild(sSelectedhub);

    }

    private void Servers_ComboBox_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        List<string> data = ServersList();
        var comboBox = sender as ComboBox;
        comboBox.ItemsSource = data;
        comboBox.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }

    private void Builds_ComboBox_DropDownClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        sSelectedServer = (string)(ServerCombo.SelectedItem);
        List<string> data = BuildsList(sSelectedServer);
        //List<string> data = ServersList();
        var comboBox = sender as ComboBox;
        comboBox.ItemsSource = data;
        comboBox.SelectedIndex = 0;
        //BuildCombo.SelectedIndex = BuildCombo.FindStringExact("test1");
        //BuildCombo.text = "test1";
    }

    private List<string> BuildsList(string sServer)
    {
        string[] sDirectories = Directory.GetDirectories(sServer);
        List<string> lBuildsList = new List<string>();

        for (int i = 0; i < sDirectories.Length; i++)
        {
            string sDirectory = sDirectories[i];
            sDirectory = sDirectory.Substring(sDirectory.LastIndexOf(@"\")).Remove(0, 1);
            lBuildsList.Add(sDirectory);
        }

        lBuildsList.Add("qa02");
        return lBuildsList;
    }

    private void Builds_ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void Builds_ComboBox_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        sSelectedServer = (string)(ServerCombo.SelectedItem);
        List<string> data = BuildsList(sSelectedServer);
        var comboBox = sender as ComboBox;
        comboBox.ItemsSource = data;
        comboBox.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }

    private void ServerCombo_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

}

Thanks!

Comment: Where does the data for these combo boxes come from? And what have you tried so far?

Comment: The ServerCombo dropdown has a fixed list of server names, the BuildCombo should be populated by specific folders that the code will get from scanning these Servers

Comment: So what have you tried so far? You may want to show a little more code - such as where and how you're setting the items of those combo boxes and how you're reacting to selection changes.

Comment: Edited to have the current code

Comment: Basic workflow: listen to changes of CB1 => trigger request => update source of CB2 (preferably with PropertyChanged event)

Answer (score 0):

SelectedServer is your dependency property for a selected server, SelectedBuild is a selected build based on SelectedServer. 
BuildsList is a list of builds based on SelectedServer.

For simplicity SelectedServer and SelectedBuild are integers but you can easily convert them to any viewmodel objects.

Also I recommended create a separate viewmodel object containing SelectedServer, SelectedBuild, BuildsList and ServerList. In this way you can make your code reusable.

MainWindow.cs:

```
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedServerProperty =
         DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedServer", typeof(int),
         typeof(MainWindow), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(0, SelectedIndexPropertyChangedCallback));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedBuildProperty =
         DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedBuild", typeof(int),
         typeof(MainWindow), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(0));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty BuildsListProperty =
         DependencyProperty.Register("BuildsList", typeof(object),
         typeof(MainWindow), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null));

    public int SelectedServer
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(SelectedServerProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectedServerProperty, value); }
    }

    public int SelectedBuild
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(SelectedBuildProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectedBuildProperty, value); }
    }

    public object BuildsList
    {
        get { return GetValue(BuildsListProperty); }
        set { SetValue(BuildsListProperty, value); }
    }


    static void SelectedIndexPropertyChangedCallback(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var window = sender as MainWindow;
        window.GenerateBuilds();
    }

    void GenerateBuilds()
    {
        var selectedServer = SelectedServer + 1;
        BuildsList = new List<string>() {
            "Build 1." + selectedServer, "Build 2." + selectedServer, "Build 3." + selectedServer };
        SelectedBuild = 0;
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        LayoutRoot.DataContext = this;
        GenerateBuilds();
    }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ComboBox SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedServer, Mode=TwoWay}">
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Server 1"></ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Server 2"></ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Server 3"></ComboBoxItem>
    </ComboBox>
    <ComboBox Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding BuildsList}" SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedBuild, Mode=TwoWay}" />
</Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: There's no need for dependency properties - implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` and raising property-changed events in the property setters is sufficient.

Comment: Well of course you're right but that's a matter of preference. Since MainWindow is already a DependencyObject I prefer to use dependency properties.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should bind your comboboxes to two ObservableCollections that implement INotifyPropertyChanged

Furthermore, extracting the folder name that way is painful, try:

```
new DirectoryInfo(path).Name;
```